# Is there a free alternate to MIrrorfolder backup

Tags: backup

Hi guys is there a free alternate to [Mirror](http://www.techsoftpl.com/backup/) folder for taking real time automated backups of files and folders. Something which I could setup once to backup certain files and folders to a location on my network and rely on it to take backups on its own periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Allway Sync](http://allwaysync.com/) has worked quite well for me.